# Xamarin.Android RecyclerView notify item changed causing problems

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, notifydatasetchanged

I seem to be having a problem whilst trying to update items in my recycler view in Xamarin.Android.

[image: PLEASE SEE THIS GIF DEMONSTRATING PROBLEM]

As shown in the GIF; what I want to achieve is when user drags an item underneath the category, I want the bar on the left hand side to change color to match the category color. The example is shown in attached GIF. As you can see, some items turn the left bar into the same color as the category but some items change completely to 'Bakery'.

My recycler view row item and category item are in the same XML layout and I am simply changing the visibility based on a few conditions..

Here is the class from my `ItemEditor` activity that saves the category once the save button has been clicked:

```
public void CategoryAdded()
    {
        // ADD CATEGORY
        HashMap categoryInfo = new HashMap();
        categoryInfo.Put("CategoryName", categoryText.Text.Trim());
        categoryInfo.Put("CategoryColor", selectedCategoryColor);
        categoryInfo.Put("CategoryPOS", "");

        var ID = MainActivity.userID;
        DatabaseReference categoryInfoRef = AppDataHelper.GetDatabase().GetReference("users/" + ID + "/Categories").Push();
        categoryInfoRef.SetValue(categoryInfo);

        // UPDATE THIS ITEM CATEGORY NAME
        AppDataHelper.GetDatabase().GetReference("users/" + MainActivity.userID + "/Shopping List/" + thisItemID + "/CategoryName").SetValue(categoryText.Text.Trim());

        // ADD CATEGORY ITEM
        HashMap itemInfo = new HashMap();
        itemInfo.Put("ItemName", categoryText.Text.Trim());
        itemInfo.Put("Quantity", "");
        itemInfo.Put("Unit", "");
        itemInfo.Put("Price", "");
        itemInfo.Put("CategoryName", categoryText.Text.Trim());
        itemInfo.Put("IsCategory", "yes");
        itemInfo.Put("Checked", "false");
        itemInfo.Put("ImageURL", "");
        itemInfo.Put("Barcode", "");
        itemInfo.Put("Notes", "");
        itemInfo.Put("Position", "");
        DatabaseReference itemInfoRef = AppDataHelper.GetDatabase().GetReference("users/" + ID + "/Shopping List").Push();
        itemInfoRef.SetValue(itemInfo);
    }
```

Here is the code that I am using in my `ItemTouchHelper` class, after the drag has been dropped:

```
public override void ClearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
        base.ClearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReOrderAdapters._itemList[viewHolderAbove].CategoryName))
        {
            AppDataHelper.GetDatabase().GetReference("users/" + MainActivity.userID + "/Shopping List/" + ReOrderAdapters._itemList[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].ID + "/CategoryName/").SetValue(ReOrderAdapters._itemList[viewHolderAbove].CategoryName);
            recyclerView.GetAdapter().NotifyItemChanged(viewHolder.AdapterPosition);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReOrderAdapters._itemList[viewHolderAbove].CategoryName))
        {
            AppDataHelper.GetDatabase().GetReference("users/" + MainActivity.userID + "/Shopping List/" + ReOrderAdapters._itemList[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].ID + "/CategoryName/").SetValue("");
            recyclerView.GetAdapter().NotifyItemChanged(viewHolder.AdapterPosition);
        }

    }
```

I am basically checking the viewHolder above where the item is dropped to check whether it contains a category name, if it does, I change the current viewHolder to match the category name..

Back in my Adapter class in `OnBindViewHolder()`

```
if (_itemList[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].IsCategory == "yes") // THIS ITEM IS A CATEGORY
            {
                viewHolder.categoryItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                viewHolder.listItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else if (_itemList[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].IsCategory != "yes" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemList[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].CategoryName)) // THIS ITEM IS NOT A CATEGORY
            {
                viewHolder.itemColorBarLeft.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
```

As you can see from the GIF, sometimes it works properly but sometimes it doesn't.

I am not sure if this problem is something to do with the viewHolder.Adapter position or whether its to do with `NotifyItemChanged()`

Hopefully someone can help me out with this.. Thank you

Comment: Could you share a sample link ?It will be helpful for testing.

Comment: Hi, a sample link to what sorry?

Comment: Do you mean a link to the entire project?

Comment: Yes,you could share a simplified project.

Comment: Give me an hour or so and I will do this

Comment: Is there any way i can share my project with you? It's all connected to firebase so it's going to be a pain to create a new simplified project

Comment: you could share it to github